# How can I make visual studio code consume less ram?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My visual studio code consumes a lot of ram which sometimes goes up to 600Mb and it blocks memory for new programs to be opened. I am a developer and this is the best IDE according to me. I think this happens if I open ts/js files, So is there anyway I can disable intellisense.

[image: Here is the ram consumption of vscode]

Comment: Disabling intellisense seems to me like it would defeat the purpose of using an IDE like VS Code. You might as well just use a plain text editor with TS code coloring.

Comment: 600Mb is not very high RAM utilization for an feature rich IDE. Probably removing the unwanted extensions and source control may help to reduce the utilization.

Comment: I only have 1 VSC process and it uses 72Mb. Exit VSC and kill all remaining VSC processes.

Comment: it can not run in 72 mb, scroll down in the task manager

Comment: Visual Studio Code is not an IDE, it is a text editor. Visual Studio is an IDE

Answer (score 1):

Read this medium article about keeping Visual Studio Code Optimized & Fast for development & productivity
[Medium Article for making VSCode faster](https://medium.com/@krtirtho/make-visual-studio-code-less-ram-consuming-faster-90db8c76a187)